# How can I quickly check which Git branch is the newest?

Tags: git, git-branch

For example if have 4 branches on git like this:

```
branch1
branch2* (current branch)
branch3 (newest commits here)
master (oldest)
```

**My questions are:**

- How can I check if my current branch is the newest right from the git command line? If not, which branch is the most up-to-date? I mean which branch contains the latest commits?
- How can I list all the commits in this git repository (in any branches) which are newer than my branch without switching away from the current branch?

Comment: By "newest branch", do you mean the branch whose tip is the most recent (easy), or the branch that was *created* last (harder)?

Comment: I mean the branch which contains "newest commit", not its creation date.

Comment: Based on @Josue Abarca answers, I now found the way to resolve this. I can simply run `git log --oneline --decorate --all 72bb..` where `72bb` is the latest commit hash of the current branch. This lists all newer commits in all other branches. :)

Comment: If you're only interested in commits reachable from branches, you should use `--branches` instead of `--all`, because the latter also lists commits that are reachable from stashes and tags.

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: You'll find relevant shell scripts in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Jubobs/git-aliases) of mine.

## Which branch is the newest?

> [...] which branch is the most up-to-date? I mean which branch contains the latest commits?

I interpret this as

> Of all the local branches, find the one whose tip is the most recent (in some sense, e.g. in terms of committer date).

`git for-each-ref` comes in handy for this; this Swiss-Army-knife command is well worth the time going through its [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref).

### Command

Let's build the command we need step by step...

1. This first command prints a list of the (short) names of all the local branches.

   ```sh
   git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' \
                    refs/heads
   ```
2. This next command does the same thing, but sorts the results by committer date, in descending order (note the `-`):

   ```sh
   git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate'     \
                    --format='%(refname:short)' \
                    refs/heads
   ```
3. This next command does the same as the previous one, but restrict the output to just one entry:

   ```sh
   git for-each-ref --count=1                   \
                    --sort='-committerdate'     \
                    --format='%(refname:short)' \
                    refs/heads
   ```

In summary, we now have a command that prints the (short) name of the most recent (in terms of committer date) branch reference: exactly what we want. Great!

### Make it an alias

For convenience, let's define an alias (called `newest-branch` below) based on it:

```sh
git config --global alias.newest-branch "for-each-ref --count=1 --sort='-committerdate' --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads"
```

### Sanity check

Now, let's run some tests in the [Git-project repo](https://github.com/git/git):

```sh
$ git branch
  maint
* master
  next
  pu
$ git newest-branch
pu

# Now print the list of all branches and the committer date of their tips
$ git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate' \
                   --format="%(refname:short)%09%(committerdate)"
                   refs/heads
pu      Tue Mar 17 16:26:47 2015 -0700
next    Tue Mar 17 16:14:11 2015 -0700
master  Tue Mar 17 16:05:12 2015 -0700
maint   Fri Mar 13 22:57:25 2015 -0700
```

`pu` is indeed the most recent branch. Yay!

---

## Is the current branch the newest?

That's easy, now that we have our `newest-branch` alias; all we have to do is compare the name of the current branch to that of the newest one. (For more robustness, you may want to use the full refname rather than the short one).

### Command

The (short) name of the current branch is given by

```sh
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
master
```

Let's compare that to the newest branch, and then print `yes` if the current branch is the newest, or `no` otherwise.

```sh
if [ $(git newest-branch) = $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) ]; then
    printf "yes\n"
else
    printf "no\n"
fi
```

### Make it an alias

Great! For convenience, let's define an alias (called `isnewest` below) for this as well:

```sh
git config --global alias.isnewest '! if [ $(git newest-branch) = $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) ]; then printf "yes\n"; else printf "no\n"; fi'
```

### Sanity check

(We already know, from the previous sanity check, that `pu` is the newest branch.)

```sh
$ git branch
  maint
* master
  next
  pu
$ git isnewest 
no
$ git checkout pu
Switched to branch 'pu'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/pu'.
$ git isnewest
yes
$ git checkout maint
Switched to branch 'maint'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/maint'.
$ git is-newest-branch 
no
```

Seems to work `(•_•)` `( •_•)>⌐■-■` `(⌐■_■)`

---

> How can I list all the commits in this git repository (in any branches) which are newer than my branch without switching away from the current branch?

If you mean newer in terms of some date, it's a hard problem. In the worst case, you'd have to explore the whole DAG, because Git doesn't forbid parents to have more recent dates than their children. If you means in terms of topological order, then it's much easier:

```
git log --branches HEAD..
```

(The `--branches` flag limits the output to commits that are reachable from at least one of the `refs/heads`.) Of course, you can tweak the output of that command by adding such cosmetic flags as `--oneline`, `--decorate`, etc.

Comment: Your solutions are awesome. Both shell script and git alias work pretty amazing! I prefer git alias solution in this case.

Comment: @TaoP.R. See my edit. My new approach is much better, I think.

Comment: You're really a git expert! The command works so well but I have just tested with a special case: let's say [pu] is the latest branch and we create a new branch [pu2] from it. Definitely [pu] and [pu2] is identical in terms of state of the code but only [pu] is found newest. Sounds strange, doesn't it? (@_@)

Comment: @TaoP.R. Thanks, but I'm still learning about Git every day :) About your comment, if there is a tie in terms of date, the lexicographical order takes over. In your example `pu2` comes after `pu` in the lexicographical order, and therefore `pu` gets listed. However, if you repeat the experiment with a branch `pt` (which comes before `pu` in the lexicographical order), then `pt` will get listed as the newest branch.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me. To me, there is a simple workaround to this such case. When I found `pu2` not the most recent branch, I may want to see what changes come after it by `git diff $(git newestbranch)` so I realize that it is identical to the latest branch already.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
git log --decorate --all --oneline --graph
```

From: man git log

- `--decorate`: Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown.
- `--all`:  Pretend as if all the refs in refs/ are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.
- `--oneline`: This is a shorthand for `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` used together.
- `--graph`: Draw a text-based graphical representation of the commit history on the left hand side of the output.

If you want to download the latest objects and refs from the remote repository, execute `git fetch` previously:

```
git fetch origin
```

Also, the command:

```
gitk
```

can help you to see all the commits and refs in a simple graphical interface.

Comment: This command is very useful indeed, but it doesn't really answer the question directly.

Comment: Oh, I have actually tried `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` but surely it showed only commits in the current branch. I just realized the argument `--all` helps me seeing all commits regardless those are not on the current branch. Very useful.

Comment: @TaoP.R. (You can upvote answers that you find useful.)

Comment: Add `--simplify-by-decoration --date-order` to the log command, that still won't exclude all tags but it's getting closer.  edit: oh, and take out `graph`, I think that might mess with the date ordering some.

Comment: @jthill You can use `--branches` instead of `--all` to only consider commits reachable from branches.

Comment: gitk is very useful.

I have tested it on both Windows 11, and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.

Thanks for sharing it.