# How to determine closest divergent branch-point

Tags: git

Not sure how to word this question.  I would imagine it's been asked for on SO so a pointer to an existing post would be great.

Complexity: Linear in number of commits, not number of named refs.  Ideally a concise sequence of git commands instead of manual loops.

Let's say I have the following commit graph:

```
A   B
|  /
| /-- C
|/
```

A & B are named refs that I start with.  For less abstract concepts, A is origin/master & B is the name of a branch that is conceptually based on A.

Finding the commits made to B that diverge from A is trivial & natively supported via the `...` notation.  I'm, however, looking to find if there's a named ref C that happens to be on the path from `A...B`.  I should *not* find C in either of the graphs below assuming D is the named ref & C is not.

```
A   B  D
|  /  / 
| /-- C
|/

A   B
|  /
| /-- C
|/    \ D
|     /
|    /
 ----
```

EDIT:
In this example assuming both C & D are named refs, I would expect to find D:

```
A   B
|  /-- D
| /-- C
|/
|
|
```

In other words, the commit closest to B that is the head of another branch.

In this example, where D & B are different refs to the same commit, I should not find D & instead find C:

```
A   B, D
|  /
| /-- C
|/
```

Comment: Have you tried using `git log --graph --oneline --all` and visually seeing where the branch diverges?

Comment: *[...] on the path from `A...B`*. In general, `A...B` is not a single commit, but a list of revisions.

Comment: @Alex: I need a programmatic answer not visual inspection.

Comment: @Jubobs: correct.  I do a diff between A...B & that's mostly fine except when I actually want C...B.  Currently I have to specify that manually by knowing I want C, but I would love for my tools to do this automatically.  So I'm looking for how to find the most recent commit that is also the head of another branch.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169162/how-can-i-quickly-check-which-git-branch-is-the-newest/29170413#29170413, for instance. You should be able to use `git-for-each-ref` to suit your needs, although that may not be the most efficient approach.

Comment: By the way, the `...` range operator is for symmetric difference. `A...B` does *not* give you a list "of the commits made to B that diverge from A". Did you mean `..` instead (two dots)?

Comment: @Jubobs: Getting off-topic here a bit but I'm pretty sure `git diff A...B` shows you the diff from A to B relative to the branch point.  `git diff A..B` is equivalent to `git diff A B` and just does a regular diff.

Comment: @Vitali Ah yes, if used with `git diff` (not with `git log`).